# Как избежать повторения авторизации при парсинге сайта?

Tags: парсер, playwright

Использую `async playwright` и `undetected_playwright` (для обхода `cloudflare`) для получения информации с сайта электронного дневника, хочу, условно, раз в 15 минут получать расписание, но приходится каждый раз авторизоваться, можно ли этого избежать и, например, оставаться постоянно на странице и каждые 15 минут ее обновлять, как это грамотно сделать, или может есть лучше реализации для моей идеи?